# Boolean Algebra simplification and factoring

Tags: boolean, discrete-mathematics, algebra, boolean-algebra

Starting from a circuit I'm able to obtain simplified the boolean expression:

```
F(A,B,C,D) = A'D' + ABC + BCD'
```

After observing the k-map I can observe that the expression BCD' (green) is covered by A'D + ABC.

[k-map of F(A,B,C,D)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hohp8.png)

How can I factor out BCD' mathematically?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related (is it **that** hard to read [ask]??)

Comment: Thanks for being helpful, Amit. I apologize if this question isn't directly programming related. I know a lot of programmers are knowlegdeable on this topic, and most are very helpful, so I gave it a try.

Comment: Maybe, but there are reasons why this (and every other q&a site) has rules, guidelines and list of relevant topics. Please don't abuse this resource.

Answer (score 1):

Use the consensus theorem

```
XY + X'Z + YZ =  XY + X'Z

A'D' + ABC + BCD' = A'D' + ABC
```

with `BCD'`  being a redundant term